# Mixed 32/64bit solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a mixed arch solution. I have few dll projects, and two exe projects (one must be compiled as 32bit, and another as 64bit).

Both exe depend on the same dll projects. All dll project have 32 and 64bit configuration. Exe project have only one configuration (one has 32bit config, the other one has 64 bit config)

Unfortunately, when I build my solution, all dlls are build only once, in globally selected configuration, so one of exe projects always gets wrong arch dlls.

Can it be solved within VS2008 buildsystem?

Answer (score 0):

If one of the exes gets the wrong dll your solution configuration is wrong.
Right-click solution and select *Configuration Manager*. Make sure you have two platforms there (*Win32* and *x64*), and that the 32bit exe is only selected for the *Win32* platform, while the 64bit exe must only be seletced for the *x64* platform.
Now when building the solution for either platform, it should always be correct since only one of the exes will be build.

You'll always have to build the solution twice though, but there are enough options to do this automatically for you: VS itself has a Batch Build dialog but I'd suggest you make a batch file that invokes vcbuild, or make a small msbuild script and run that.